# Outlook Add-inn - Need to merge two manifest

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have tried merging two different example but when merged I am not getting any output - where as the example works fine on its own.

---

I am trying to merge two different example into a single solution for Outlook Add inn

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#code-examples

Where I have moved the code to the first example but I am trying to merge both the Manifest file but I am not sure

Original manifest One

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>954970fa-d22e-45d9-a648-913b9d754fda</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>civiCRM</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="CiviCRM"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Connect CiviCRM Database from Cloud."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>

  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
              <!-- Message Compose -->
              <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Title"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertDefaultGist">
                    <Label resid="FunctionButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="FunctionButton.Title"/>
                      <Description resid="FunctionButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>insertDefaultGist</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3001/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Git the gist"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
          <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
          <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Displays a list of your gists and allows you to insert their contents into the current message."/>
          <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Inserts the content of the gist you mark as default into the current message."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
  </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Original Manifest second

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <OfficeApp   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>D0590B2A-0CB8-4B4F-AD70-C520AFA6E3FC</Id>   <Version>1.0</Version>   <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>   <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>   <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso Message Body Checker" />   <Description DefaultValue="Contoso Message Body Checker" />

  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>   </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>   </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />   </Rule>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
            <!-- In this particular case the function validateBody will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Urls>
           <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
          <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" ></bt:Url>
        </bt:Urls>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>   </VersionOverrides> </OfficeApp>
```

Merged code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" 
xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>954970fa-d22e-45d9-a648-913b9d754fda</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>civiCRM</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="CiviCRM"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Connect CiviCRM Database from Cloud."/>

  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>

  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/taskpane.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
  </Rule>

  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
              <!-- Message Compose -->
              <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertGist">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Title"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgComposeInsertDefaultGist">
                    <Label resid="FunctionButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="FunctionButton.Title"/>
                      <Description resid="FunctionButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>insertDefaultGist</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/commands.html"/>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/taskpane.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Git the gist"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert gist"/>
          <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
          <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Title" DefaultValue="Insert default gist"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Displays a list of your gists and allows you to insert their contents into the current message."/>
          <bt:String id="FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Inserts the content of the gist you mark as default into the current message."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
  </Resources>

      <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
            <!-- In this particular case the function validateBody will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
              <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Urls>
           <!-- The JavaScript code is hosted on a secure and trusted web server. -->
          <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" ></bt:Url>
        </bt:Urls>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Just wanted to know is this possible or not - Also need to know the mistake I have done

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give more information about what issue you have when you say you are not getting any output? I was able to successfully install the merged manifest and the OnSend functionality prevented mail from being sent.

Comment: Hi - I have tested both the example on its own and it is working separately - But when I try to install both the manifest together I am not getting the output correctly - I am not sure what to do

Comment: Merged manifest of the application loaded without issues. Hook for Onsend event works. Obviously I don't have any code running, so cannot proceed any further. You would need to debug your application and find out what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Just a note of caution, I would suggest using an <Id> that is unique and different from both, or you have to manage the version numbers by increasing them or at least changing them each time, to ensure clients like Outlook desktop will pull the new manifest down.  Other than that, if you could provide more details as to what exactly is not working.

Comment: Forgot to mention - when I try to merge both the example I did copied App.js file from one example and I didn't have any app.js file in the other example - So I did dropped app.js in the root folder and started to test -

Comment: I think your App.js contains the `validateBody` function. And it is included in the `index.html` referenced in the merged code. If that is true, then you should be able to uninstall the previous manifests and installed the merged one, and your add-in should work.